# to Delete item at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flex3

I have created some shapes dynamically at run time by mouse drag, Now i want to delete any selected item  the white board.How can i achieve that.
Currently i am able to delete the last drawn item through "removeChild()" method, but not the previous items.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily i got my answer very soon.
To delete multiple items at run time i've assign the ids to them dyanimically and the done the following:

**parentComponent.removeChild(parent.getChildByName("itemName"));**

before trying this i was doing

**parentComponent.removeChild(item);**

Cheers !!!